# .NET ComboBox Autocomplete failing on slashes

Tags: .net, combobox, autocomplete

The .NET ComboBox autocomplete will not fully autocomplete with the display text contains a slash.  It completes only up to the slash, leaving SelectedIndex == -1 and SelectedValue == null.

This behavior stupidly persists no matter whether your autocompletesource is set to ListItems rather than FileSystem or URL.

Is there any workaround for this that doesn't involve just throwing the ComboBox class away and writing a "MyComboBox" class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like MS is well aware of this behavior. I suspect you've seen the note on their docs page, if not the link to it is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.autocompletemode.aspx).

Comment: yes I've seen the note.  But I found no solution on that page.

Comment: You've probably seen this 'solution' too then:  http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/55c91e04-0cbd-4189-84be-cb1258447ae5/

Comment: Were you ever able to get a solution to this? I know this comment is a decade too late but they still don't seem to have a fix

Answer (score 1):

@hal9000 I was looking for a fix as well, I found a piece of code by Paul Cull on the msdn website:

```
Private Sub cbCode_Validating(sender As Object, e As 
System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles cbCode.Validating
   
Dim s As String
   
If cbCode.SelectedIndex = -1 And cbCode.Text <> "" Then
' Let's see if it ends with a slash
 s = cbCode.Text
 If s.EndsWith("\") Or s.EndsWith("/") Then cbCode.SelectedIndex = cbCode.FindString(s)
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution that I could find is to download syncfusion's free community winforms controls package from [syncfusion.com](https://www.syncfusion.com) and use their sfCombobox. The autocomplete on theirs works properly. Microsoft should really fix this issue though its quite a pain.