# WinForm TextBox AutoComplete stops at "/" Slash char

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio

I have a WinForm TextBox's AutoCompleteMode is set to SuggestAppend. This TextBox has an AutoCompleteCustomSource which is a list of company names.

If the autocomplete item name has a "/" slash in it, then the auto complete will only display partial text up to the "/" character.

For example, if we have a company name like "ABC Energy P/L", the auto complete will only display "ABC Energy P/" without L.

I digged around and found this reply.
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winforms/thread/55c91e04-0cbd-4189-84be-cb1258447ae5
It pointed out that the autocomplete is broken out of the box, and no one in MS borthers to go back and put an if statement to patch it. But I am not happy to take that as an answer. I hope someone out there will have a better solution than rewriting the auto(in)complete control.

Comment: possible duplicate of [.NET ComboBox Autocomplete failing on slashes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/685771/net-combobox-autocomplete-failing-on-slashes)

Comment: @ISE, thanks for giving the social.msdn link i provided back to me. that link is broken, too, if you bother to click it. So please, if you don't know how to answer it, at least don't vote to close my question. because it is legit and has no answer yet.