# Combo box auto completing is not working properly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

Iam working with Vb in VS 2008.
I have a combobox with auto completed mode = suggestappend and auto complete source = List items.

[Text appending like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UD7zo.png)

text is not completely appending to the combobox. appending text stops at / 
and .
i want to append complete text.

How can i rectify this problem.

Comment: 1. Show your complete code 2. Show the actual results and what you expect to be correct

Comment: I did not written any code for auto complete, just i used auto complete mode and auto complete source properties. i want output like "remarks/new", but its appending up to "remarks/" and remaining text is not appending.

Comment: Just i found on google about this as following " System_CAPS_noteNote
The operating system might limit the number of custom strings that it can display at once. For strings that contain a forward slash (/) or backward slash (\), automatic completion appends all characters only up to and including the slash".

Comment: As you already mentioned this is a known bug by .NET. Microsoft is aware of it but the bug is pretty old (around 2007) so I doubt it´s ever gonna be fixed. You have to either use another separator char than a backslash, code your own AutoComplete (it´s not that hard and there are examples around SO) or you create your own ComboBox control (like mentioned in the answer from your quote you posted).

Comment: Did you ever end up getting a solution to this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [.NET ComboBox Autocomplete failing on slashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/685771/net-combobox-autocomplete-failing-on-slashes)